# There's something wrong about Files.isWritable

Tags: java, io

The server : 192.168.0.18/share is a samba server , and all of can write to the path

```
Files.write(Paths.get(URI.create("file://192.168.0.18/share/aa/aaaa")), "asd34234asdasd".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);


System.out.println(Files.isWritable(Paths.get(URI.create("file://192.168.0.18/share/aa/aaaa"))));
```

I found that the first line really create a file add append the text in it.

But the second line return false .

I didn't know why .

And I try JDK7_u5 & u13 .

Thanks .

Comment: From the API Docs: `Returns: true if the file exists and is writable; false if the file does not exist, write access would be denied because the Java virtual machine has insufficient privileges, or access cannot be determined`. Basically, `false` doesn't mean you can't write. It just means the JVM doesn't know that you can.

Comment: On Windows this is broken.  Even with Java 8u5, isWritable will also return true when you don't have permission to write.

Answer (score 0):

If `"file://192.168.0.18/share/aa/aaaa"` does not exists when you check it, you should test the writable flag on the (existing) directory `"file://192.168.0.18/share/aa/"` as in:

```
Path target=Paths.get(URI.create("file://192.168.0.18/share/aa/aaaa");
if (Files.exists(target)){  // check existing file
    System.out.println(Files.isWritable(target));
}else{ // check directory
    System.out.println(Files.isWritable(target.getParent()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing to a share the file attributes aren't always available and so what the code is telling you is that it cant determine whether or not the file is readable.

This is true a lot of the time when doing file manipulations on a file system thats actually hosted by a different operating system - the low level file attributes aren't always exposed to the client.

If you did `new File(<your file>).exists()` it would almost certainly return `true`, so to determine if the cause of what you're seeing is indeed attribute related you could try either:

```
DosFileAttributes attr =Files.readAttributes(<your file>, DosFileAttributes.class);
```

or

```
PosixFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(<your file>, PosixFileAttributes.class);
```

And interrogate the results to see if you get meaningful/expected attributes back